# Serialisation and Deserialisation over clrmq

Tags: c#, serialization, zeromq

I am currently in the process of designing a networking wrapper in C# using the clrmq binding for ZeroMQ.

My problem is that I am trying to think of a way to do deserialization and serialization 
transparently; that is, the networking wrapper can transmit any object as bytes without knowing or caring about its type and can deserialize to the correct type on the other end.

I have a class heirachy as follows

```
public interface ITransmission
{
    Type Type { get; }
}

public abstract class Transmission<T> : ITransmission
{
    public Type Type { get { return typeof(T); } }
}
```

The idea is to serialize objects that have implemented the Transmission type;transmit 
them over clrmq as bytes and deserialize them at the other end

My ideal solution would

1. Be capable of serializing any type of object with no attribute decoration or very minimal attribute decoration to preferably a byte array format (hence the idea above using the Transmission object)
2. Be able to deserialize the received byte array format to a typed object

What are people currently using or doing to resolve the issue of serializing and deserialising transparently? Speed will be a factor at some point but at this time , I'm just trying to find out what the options are.

Is the implied limitation here that the networking libraries will need to have references to all the assemblies containing the types to be transmitted?

Additionally, the other question would be whether this a feasible approach to take, or should a server and client be strongly typed from the get go?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: Is speed a critical factor here? I had done something similar in the past with reflection. It was years ago, but in a nutshell what I did was have some code that would use reflection to iterate over each member in an object and then pack that into a byte array. The receiving end did the same in reverse. It was incredibly flexible and IMO quite slick

Comment: Hiya, speed will be a factor at some point but right now i am just gathering ideas. How fast/slow was your solution? Could I use the type information in the interface to make it faster?

Comment: It was fast enough for my needs which was fairly high performance requirement (it was actually a 2D online multiplayer game)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User dferraro's solution is a good one. But I think these days one can do *a lot* better with serialization in C#. I would strongly suggest you pair **ZeroMQ** as the transport with Google's **Protobuf** framework for the serialization and messaging component.

Have a look at the .NET implementation of [Protobuf here](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/). I won't go into too much detail on the implementation side of it as its pretty documented and there are a lot of nice questions here on StackOverflow about it already. In fact, the author of the C# implementation of Protobuf - [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell) - idles on SO often and will respond to any questions with the [protobuf-net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/protobuf-net) tag.

Comment: that was 6 or 7 years ago when I came up with that ;). I figured it was dated. I had never heard of this protobuf thing but it looks awesome. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 1):

I was able to do this successfully in an online multiplayer game using Reflection which might suit your needs depending on your requirements.

Here's a link that described how I did it: http://www.gamedev.net/topic/436066-please-critique-my-serialization-system-net--reflection/

In a nutshell, here is how I serialized/Derialized my data: I created a class called 'GameMessage' which used reflection to serialize/deserialize itself. Then every message type would simply inherit from this class and magically have a ToByte() function and constructor accepting a byte[] work for it:

```
public class GameMessage 
    {

        private static int SortFieldInfo(FieldInfo left, FieldInfo right)
        {
            if (left.Equals(right))
            {
                return 0;
            }

            if (right.Name == "ID")
                return 1;
            else if (right.FieldType.Name == "String")
                return -1;
            else 
                return 0;
        }
        public GameMessage(){}
        public GameMessage(byte[] data)
        {
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
            List<FieldInfo> info = new List<FieldInfo>(this.GetType().GetFields());

            info.Sort(SortFieldInfo);
            int idx = 0;

            for (int i = 0; i < info.Count; i++)
            {
                if (info[i].FieldType.Name == "String")// is string)
                {
                    string value;
                    UInt16 size;

                    if (i != info.Count - 1)
                    {
                        size = BitConverter.ToUInt16(data, idx);
                        idx += 2;

                        value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data, idx, size);
                        idx += size;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        value = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(data, idx, data.Length - idx);
                        idx += data.Length - idx;
                    }

                    info[i].SetValue(this,value);
                }
                else
                {
                    if (info[i].Name != "ID")
                    {
                        Type[] types = new Type[2] { data.GetType(), idx.GetType() };
                        object[] values = new object[2] { data, idx };

                        info[i].SetValue(this, typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("To" + info[i].FieldType.Name, types).Invoke(null, values));
                        idx += Marshal.SizeOf(info[i].FieldType);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        idx += sizeof(ID);
                    }
                }
            }

        }
        public byte[] ToByte()
        {
            List<byte> bytes = new List<byte>();
            List<FieldInfo> info = new List<FieldInfo>(this.GetType().GetFields());
            info.Sort(SortFieldInfo);

            for(int i=0;i<info.Count;i++)
            {
                if (info[i].FieldType.Name == "String")
                {
                    if (i != info.Count - 1)
                    {
                        bytes.AddRange(BitConverter.GetBytes(((UInt16)((string)info[i].GetValue(this)).Length)));
                    }

                    bytes.AddRange(ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes((string)info[i].GetValue(this)));
                }
                else
                {
                    bytes.AddRange((byte[])typeof(BitConverter).GetMethod("GetBytes", new Type[] { info[i].FieldType }).Invoke(null, new object[] { info[i].GetValue(this) }));
                }
          }

            return bytes.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Extremely thorough answer, and thanks for the sample code. I did however end up looking at protobuf instead :)